# "Guess" method arguments in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Eclipse has a feature, where it "guesses" arguments for a method call, based on types (and probably variable names?). Is there an equivalent in IntelliJ? I know Smart Complete should be capable of completing multiple arguments, but it doesn't work as good (especially when there is more than one String argument for example).

EDIT: It's called "Insered best guessed arguments" in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDEA doesn't support it, [see the related feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5496).

Answer (score 5):

There is `Ctrl+Shift+Space` (Smart-Type, I think), but as of this writing, it's crap and doesn't go the whole hog.

Despite being an Eclipse fan, I've always openly acknowledge that if Eclipse can do it, IntelliJ can probably do it better... not this time, how dissappointing q(`_`!)p

Answer (score 3):

Try

(Ctrl+P) for Windows/Linux

Or

(Cmd+P) for OS X

this lists you the parameters for a method.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept a very basic low tech version of this, you could try this Gist
https://gist.github.com/kontext-e/f68c6a1b90dd862afb5d
for IDEAs LivePlugin.
Please ping me if there is some interest that I should make a real plugin out of this.